# Issue with scrolling in Puppeteer

Tags: javascript, node.js, function, web-scraping, puppeteer

I'm trying to scroll down a page in a puppeteer framework. Im really new at this and for sure am missing something stupid. I've tried "scrollToBottom" and "scrollDown" but I keep getting the error that they aren't functions. Any ideas?

Thank you for your time

Comment: Yes `scrollToBottom/scrollDown` are not standard functions. You need to define them before using.

Answer (score 1):

Have you try this function?

```
await page.evaluate ( () => {
    window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight) 
})
```

If this method is not working, then you've to select the correct scrolling element.